# How can I pack 16 bytes in python with struct?

Tags: python-3.x, packing

How can i pack 16 bytes by using `struct.pack` ?
I don't see in the man format for that.

```
res = struct.pack(">???", 1234123412341234)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are there 16 bytes in your question? You entered a single integer number. You are aware that for the 16 digits that represent this number in decimal would only be  "16 bytes" if this was an encoded string, with each byte representing one ASCII char, right?

And if you have a byte-string (which is the same as an encoded string), it is *already* packed as 16 bytes: no need to do anything.

I mean:

```
In [8]: a = "1234123412341234".encode()

In [9]: type(a)
Out[9]: bytes

In [10]: len(a)
Out[10]: 16

In [11]: list(a)
Out[11]: [49, 50, 51, 52, 49, 50, 51, 52, 49, 50, 51, 52, 49, 50, 51, 52]

In [12]: a[0]
Out[12]: 49

In [13]: chr(a[0])
Out[13]: '1'
```

Comment: so if i want to write 16 bytes (of zeros) to binary file, how i need to write it to the file ?

Comment: `f = open("binaryfile.bin", "wb"); f.write(b"\x00" * 16) `.  Or you can just pass an integer to the `bytes` constructor: it will create a sequence of that many bytes with '0':  `f = open("binaryfile.bin", "wb"); f.write(bytes(16))`

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, and one more small question in this context. If I want to create a binary file so that I want to allocate several parts in the binary file that I want to create, part 1, part 2, and part 3 (for example), and to each part assign a certain number of bytes. For example: assign 8 bytes to part 1. For part 2 assign16 bytes. and to part 3 assign 4 bytes. how can i do that?

Comment: You'd better creating a proper Python class to do it - you could use ctypes Struct and Fields - or have a class that holds its data in a bytearray object, and write property-es to store/get your binary values from the appropriate places on that bytearray.

All in all, this is not a 'small' question - as a proper answer would be larger than the original answer here.

Comment: just go and ask a new question, detailing the fields you need to read/write, their sizes, and some code with what  you tying to for now - you could get some nice answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143329/how-can-i-create-a-binary-file-in-python

Comment: @jsbueno Hi, can you answer about this question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143329/how-can-i-create-a-binary-file-in-python (it's will be interesting to see you answer about this question)