# How can I create a binary file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, struct, binary, binaryfiles

I want to create a new binary file by using python according to the following format:

```
< Part1: 8 bytes > < Part2: 4 bytes > < Part3: 16 bytes>
```

so that i will write to any part some value and if this value is not the size of that part, then there will be a complement of zeros for that part.

I looking for the best way and the most efficient way to do it.

I read in the internet that I can do something like that:

```
f = open('file', 'w+b')
res = struct.pack(">l", 0000)
f.write(res)
```

but I don't sure that i can by this way to keep a place from the hand.

Comment: 16 bytes is a very unusual field length for an integer. Are you packing some other information into the part3 field?

Comment: @ukBaz It doesn't have to be an Integer but an area of 16 bytes that I will assign a certain data there.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some terminology when working with Python data before getting to your code to write a binary file.

***Note:** The experiments below are using the [Python REPL](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-interective-shell)*

An integer in Python can be written as a denary/decimal number (e.g. `1`)

```py
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
```

It can also be written in hex by adding a leading `0x`:

```py
>>> 0x1
1
>>> type(0x1)
<class 'int'>
```

A hex integer's leading zeros have no effect. While in denary they give an error:

```py
>>> x = 0x0001
>>> print(x)
1
>>> x = 0001

    x = 0001
        ^^^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

When writing to a binary file it is bytes that need to get written. If the content is an integer it can be converted to bytes with either the `int.to_bytes` functionality or the `struct` library functionality.

To convert `1` to bytes using `int.to_bytes`:

```py
>>> int(1).to_bytes(length=1, byteorder='little')
b'\x01'
```

With a length of 1 the byte order (endianness) is not important. For numbers stored in more bytes it is important.

```py
>>> int(1).to_bytes(length=4, byteorder='little')
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
>>> int(1).to_bytes(length=4, byteorder='big')
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

The same result can be achieved with the struct library:

```py
>>> struct.pack('<l', 1)
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.pack('>l', 1)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

The other common way to see values written is a `hex string`. The denary value of `1` could be written as `01000000` or `00000001` to represent 1 in different endian in 4 bytes.

```py
>>> int(1).to_bytes(length=4, byteorder='big').hex()
'00000001'
>>> int(1).to_bytes(length=4, byteorder='little').hex()
'01000000'
```

In your question you have written `0000` for the value to be converted using struct and written to a file.

```
f = open('file', 'w+b')
res = struct.pack(">l", 0000)
f.write(res)
```

`0000` will work but `0001` will give the `SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted;`

I think what you have in your question is the hex string representation of the value you want written.
If it is a hex string you are trying to input then the following will work:

```py
f = open('file', 'w+b')
res = bytes.fromhex('0001')
f.write(res)
```

The other piece in your question was about making the values to certain byte length.

If your hex string represents the correct byte length then you are good.
However the example you gave was only 2 bytes long:

```py
bytes.fromhex('0001')
b'\x00\x01'
len(bytes.fromhex('0001'))
2
```

And you wanted fields of either 4, 8, or 16 bytes long in which case the bytes have to be "padded` with bytes of zero value to get the correct number of bytes. e.g.

```py
>>> bytes.fromhex('0001').rjust(4, b'\x00')
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> bytes.fromhex('0001').rjust(8, b'\x00')
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> bytes.fromhex('0001').rjust(16, b'\x00')
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

If the hex string are in little endian format then `ljust` would be required:

```py
bytes.fromhex('0100').ljust(4, b'\x00')
b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: if i know the content of the binary file according to hex values, how can i write it to the binary file? (instead of the part of your `token_bytes`)

Comment: For example, i want the `part_i` will be for `field_i` with max size (for part 1 - the max size is 8 bytes, and for part 2 - the max size is 4 bytes, and for part 3 - the max size is 16 bytes).