# What is the format of 16 bytes in struct in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, byte, pack

I writed the following code:

```
field_size_4_bytes = 0
field_size_2_bytes = 0
field_size_16_bytes = 0
res = struct.pack('<lh?', field_size_4_bytes , field_size_2_bytes , field_size_16_bytes )
                      ^
```

And my question is what i need to write instead of the `?` for the format of the value of 16 bytes?

Comment: There is no 16-byte number type. Most other languages don't have integers larger than 4 or 8 bytes, and there are no serialization protocols that use larger integers, so there's no need for a larger type. Byte arrays are used for larger data.

Comment: @Barmar So can you explain by code how can i do it in other ways ?

Comment: I think some more context about what you are trying to do might be helpful to give a better answer, but you can do it with the `int.to_bytes` functionality. For example 1 int(field_size_4_bytes).to_bytes(4, 'little', signed=True) + int(field_size_2_bytes).to_bytes(2, 'little', signed=True) + int(field_size_16_bytes).to_bytes(16, 'little', signed=True)`

Comment: @ukBaz I think that this is what that he trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143329/how-can-i-create-a-binary-file-in-python

Comment: @Barmar In fact, this is very interesting question, how you can in python to create a binary file which is split to sections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143329/how-can-i-create-a-binary-file-in-python

Comment: Today I checked format `q` for signed and `Q` for unsigned 8 bytes is available.Link https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html